# Nuxt2 + ts how to fix a bug?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I have code. Use Nuxt.js 2 option api + ts

```
computed: {
      form: {
        get: () => this.value,
        set: (value) => this.$emit('input', value)
      }
    }
```

and errors

1. TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
2. TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the value type first and try again

for example:

```
computed: {
      form: {
        get: () => this.value,
        set: (value: string | number) => this.$emit('input', value)
      }
    }
```